# OpenDaylight Aluminium Clustering Setup Issue

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am using mininet and ODL controller cluster in my SDN application testbed scenario.

The first issue is the controller ports ('6633' and '6653') are not working after clustering setup in ODL.

So, I cannot connect the remote controller from my mininet and the following error is shown in mininet.

[image: Cannot connect to remote controller]

Before, clustering setup all the hosts are reachable each other, however, after making clustering setup, pingall failed and even the mininet cannot connect to remote controllers.

I did the clustering setup in my ODL controller clusters with three controllers.

However, the following exception error is shown in two controllers after restarting the controller.

Is this also related with ODL controller '6633' and '6653' port not working issue?

> raziel@raziel-opendaylight2:~/opendaylight-0.13.1$ bin/karaf Apache Karaf
> starting up. Press Enter to open the shell now...  93%
> [==================================================================>
> ]ERROR : bundle
> org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:2.0.6
> (216)[org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.OSGiDistributedDataStore(15)]
> : The activate method has thrown an exception
> java.lang.RuntimeException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask
> timed out on
> [Actor[akka://opendaylight-cluster-data/user/$a#1033082773]] after
> [30000 ms]. Message of type
> [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.GetClientRequest].
> A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor
> didn't send a reply.  at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.AbstractDataStoreClientActor.getDistributedDataStoreClient(AbstractDataStoreClientActor.java:59)
> at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.AbstractDataStore.(AbstractDataStore.java:108)
> at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.DistributedDataStore.(DistributedDataStore.java:32)
> at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.DistributedDataStoreFactory.createInstance(DistributedDataStoreFactory.java:84)
> at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.OSGiDistributedDataStore.createDatastore(OSGiDistributedDataStore.java:154)
> at
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.OSGiDistributedDataStore.activate(OSGiDistributedDataStore.java:129)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:244)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:685)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:529)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:318)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:308)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:354)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:115)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:1000)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:973)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:785)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1271)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1222)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1200)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1121)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:928)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:864)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1152)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator$ListenerInfo.serviceChanged(BundleComponentActivator.java:114)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:920)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1271)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1222)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1200)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1121)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:928)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:864)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1152)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator$ListenerInfo.serviceChanged(BundleComponentActivator.java:114)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:920)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ComponentFactoryImpl.newInstance(ComponentFactoryImpl.java:132)
> at
> org.opendaylight.mdsal.dom.schema.osgi.impl.RegularYangModuleInfoRegistry.updateService(RegularYangModuleInfoRegistry.java:99)
> at
> org.opendaylight.mdsal.dom.schema.osgi.impl.RegularYangModuleInfoRegistry.enableScannerAndUpdate(RegularYangModuleInfoRegistry.java:67)
> at
> org.opendaylight.mdsal.dom.schema.osgi.impl.KarafYangModuleInfoRegistry.enableScannerAndUpdate(KarafYangModuleInfoRegistry.java:72)
> at
> org.opendaylight.mdsal.dom.schema.osgi.impl.OSGiModelRuntime.activate(OSGiModelRuntime.java:38)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:244)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:685)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:529)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:318)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.methods.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:308)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:354)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:115)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:1000)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:973)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:785)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1271)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1222)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1200)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1121)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:928)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:864)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1152)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator$ListenerInfo.serviceChanged(BundleComponentActivator.java:114)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:920)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1271)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:1222)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1200)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1121)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:928)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:864)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1152)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator$ListenerInfo.serviceChanged(BundleComponentActivator.java:114)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:920)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:437)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:667)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:305)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:554)
> at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:70)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:421)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:196)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:49)
> at
> org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
> at
> org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:415)
> at
> org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
> at
> org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)     at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
> Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on
> [Actor[akka://opendaylight-cluster-data/user/$a#1033082773]] after
> [30000 ms]. Message of type
> [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.GetClientRequest].
> A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor
> didn't send a reply.  at
> akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:648)
> at
> akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:669)
> at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:202)    at
> scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$parasitic$.execute(ExecutionContext.scala:164)
> at
> akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:334)
> at
> akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:285)
> at
> akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:289)
> at
> akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:241)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>
> 100%
> [========================================================================] Karaf started in 47s. Bundle stats: 393 active, 394 total
>
> ```
> ________                       ________                .__  .__       .__     __       
> \_____  \ ______   ____   ____ \______ \ _____  ___.__.|  | |__| ____ |  |___/  |_     
>  /   |   \\____ \_/ __ \ /    \ |    |  \\__  \<   |  ||  | |  |/ ___\|  |  \   __\    
> /    |    \  |_> >  ___/|   |  \|    `   \/ __ \\___  ||  |_|  / /_/  >   Y  \  |      
> \_______  /   __/ \___  >___|  /_______  (____  / ____||____/__\___  /|___|  /__|      
>         \/|__|        \/     \/        \/     \/\/            /_____/      \/
> ```
>
> Hit '' for a list of available commands and '[cmd] --help' for
> help on a specific command. Hit '' or type 'system:shutdown'
> or 'logout' to shutdown OpenDaylight.
>
> opendaylight-user@root>WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation
> has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
> org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil
> (file:/home/ye/opendaylight-0.13.1/data/cache/org.eclipse.osgi/184/0/bundleFile)
> to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner() WARNING: Please consider
> reporting this to the maintainers of
> org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil WARNING: Use
> --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
> denied in a future release

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you changed your akka.conf

In your case the configuration of the first member would probably look like this:

```
odl-cluster-data {
  akka {
    remote {
      artery {
        enabled = off
        canonical.hostname = "192.168.122.17"
        canonical.port = 2550
      }
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "192.168.122.17"
        port = 2550
      }
    }
    cluster {
      seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://192.168.122.17:2550",
      "akka.tcp://192.168.122.25:2550",
      "akka.tcp://192.168.122.221:2550",
      ]
      roles = ["member-0"]
    }
    persistence {
      # By default the snapshots/journal directories live in KARAF_HOME. You can choose to put it somewhere else by
      # modifying the following two properties. The directory location specified may be a relative or absolute path.
      # The relative path is always relative to KARAF_HOME.
      # snapshot-store.local.dir = "target/snapshots"
      # journal.leveldb.dir = "target/journal"
      journal {
        leveldb {
# Set native = off to use a Java-only implementation of leveldb.
# Note that the Java-only version is not currently considered by Akka to be production quality.
# native = off
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the second and the third node just change the `canonical.hostname` `hostname` and `roles` lines accordingly.

If you manage to get your Akka cluster up and running, then try Openflow controller again.
This might help: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3327731

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the way you mentioned above, however, the error from akka is still shown as below:  ERROR : bundle org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:2.0.6 (216)[org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.akka.osgi.impl.OSGiActorSystemProvider(10)] : The activate method has thrown an exception
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: ./configuration/initial/akka.conf: 39: unbalanced close brace '}' with no open brace (if you intended '}' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)
 at com.typesafe.config.impl.Config$"

Comment: The problem is openflow ports 6653 and 6633 are not working after making clustering. Is there any way to solve my issue?

Comment: Could you please share the output of "bundle:list" ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install l2switch-switch, so that controller can listen on 6633/6653. Try and let me know.
Or if you find the solution? I have having same issue, no port 6633 after clustering, tried everything possible for me.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the akka.conf and module-shards.conf
start by " **sudo JAVA_MAX_MEM=4G JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM=512M ./karaf clean**"
with clean, it restart everything from base using those file. So now, install odl-l2switch-switch.
Then you have all three controller listening. If further problem do contact me.

I have been learning myself since 2 months and everything seems trial and error [final launch image from mn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKqXj.png)